# How to setValue of a field by prompt() through adhoc CS in Netsuite?

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

I created a Button through UE script in Purchase Order. On hitting an alert/prompt would let the user write the text and on hitting OK in prompt box , that text would be saved in a custombody field.
I tried to do `submitFields` but it doesn't do anything. Can anyone help me with this?

User event code:

```
        context.form.addButton({
            id: 'custpage_reject',
            label: 'Reject With Reason',
            functionName: 'rejectButton()'
        })
        context.form.clientScriptModulePath = 'SuiteScripts/mx_rejectionReason_cs.js';
```

Client script function:

```
function rejectButton() {
    rejectReasonValue = window.prompt("Reason for Rejection ?");
    console.log('prompt:', rejectReasonValue)

    nsCurrentRecord.submitFields({
        type: recType,
        id: recId,
        values: {
          custbody_reasonof_rejection: rejectReasonValue,
        },
        options: {
          enableSourcing: true,
          ignoreMandatoryFields: true
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Hi. How are you getting your "recId" in the client script?

Comment: from currentRecord module

Comment: I think there might be a problem with the fact that you're using submitFields for a currently loaded record. Might be worth trying nsCurrentRecord.setValue();

Comment: oh.. ok. So i try touse setValue(); than. Thanks Carl!

Comment: I've posted my suggestion as an answer, please let me know if this works for you

Comment: yes it did work. thank alot carl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Hi

I think your submitFields wouldn't work on the currently loaded record.

Try setting the field value on the current record like so:

```
currentRecord.setValue('custbody_reasonof_rejection', rejectReasonValue);
```

Hope this works for you!